# Automatically attaching specified suffixes to text in Excel

Tags: excel

I am trying to come up with a way to attach a specified suffix to a string of text in Excel, but only when it matches another string.

Example:

I have a list that contains several domains:

```
xyz.blogspot.com,
abc.blogspot.co.uk,
edf.blogspot.co.jp
```

For each of these, I want to strip off the suffix (.com, .co.uk etc) and apply a new suffix from a list I have (.com, .co.uk, .co.jp, .in, .br etc).

The idea is that when I see xyz.blogspot.com, I can instantly and automatically create all possible variations of that domain name.

Any help appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling this will not suit (but seems to answer the question):

```
=LEFT($A2,LEN($A$1)+FIND($A$1,A2)-1)&B$1
```

copied across and down to suit.

[image: SO22485173 examle]